# Where to place my loading controller when using pipe and subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to have a loading controller which is loading until there is the data from the api. Now since I'm using pipe and subscribe I don't know where I have to place my loading controller function. I normally would just initialize the loader right after the the `this.authService.apilogin()` call but in my variant I somehow can't do that since I have my pipe there and I get an error. Where should I place my loader function?

page.ts

```
apiSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;

  // if form is invalid => stop
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.authService.apilogin(
  this.f.username,
  this.f.password)
  this.loadingController // Ladebalken ->User kann nichts machen
  .create({keyboardClose: true, message: 'Logging in...', spinner: 'crescent'})
  .then(loadingEl => {
    loadingEl.present();
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          this.isLoading = false;
          loadingEl.dismiss();
        },
        error => {
          this.error = error;
          this.isLoading = false;
          loadingEl.dismiss();
        }

      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about keeping a reference to `loadingEl`?

```
  loadingEl : any;

  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    this.loadingController.create().then(x => this.loadingEl = x)
  }

  apiSubmit() {
    this.loadingEl.present()
    this.authService.apilogin(this.f.username, this.f.password)
      .pipe(
        tap(x => this.loadingEl.dismiss()),
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]),
        error => this.error = error
      )
  }
```